# como compartir ubicacion a diferetes app

Tags: android-studio, mapa, position, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Tengo mi aplicación de mapa con el kit de huawei , como puedo hacer para compartir mi ubicación otras personas y ellos pueda abrir desde cualquier aplicación de mapas?? no encuentro ejemplos de ellos agradeceré sus ayudas.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado? Si solo dices tengo este deber resuelvan no es bien recibido.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar este código

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:"+latitud+","+longitud);
Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```